# Check if GPS Point exists within Polygon

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, latitude-longitude

In our application we have a map where user can draw polygon and select event time range.

There are two types of sources attached with event:

1. Static Source (POLE CAMERA)
2. Dynamic Source (MOVING CAR CAMERA)

In event table, If new entry is coming from static source, we already have GPS value for it saved in source table, so we save just source id and keep plateGPS field blank, but for Dynamic source we do not have GPS value in source table because source is dynamic and each event has different location which is saved in plateGps field of event table along with sourceId pointing to source table
 (just for reference).

**Event**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event` (
          `eventId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `eventTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 1431201865000 (epoch is milliseconds)',
          `sourceId` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: pole-code: 1 = JA005, patrolCarCode: 5000 = D4588',
          `plateNumber` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 5849',
          `plateGps` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 0.000000 N  0.000000 E') 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Source**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `source` (
  `sourceId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sourceName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: pole-code: JA005, patrolCarCode:D4588',
  `sourceSimIp` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 192.55.44.22',
  `sourceGps` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Only for Fixed source (Poles) ex: 25.110227 N  55.239798 E, 24.993183 N  55.250382 E, 0.000000 N  0.000000 E',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sourceId`),
  KEY `sourceName` (`sourceName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Sample Table Data**

```
INSERT INTO `source` (`sourceId`, `sourceName`, `sourceSimIp`, `sourceGps`) VALUES
    (1, 'Pole 1', '74.200.230.71', '7.8731 N  80.7718 E'),
    (2, 'Car 1', '40.214.203.72', '')


INSERT INTO `event` (`eventId`, `eventTime`, `sourceId`, `plateNumber`, `plateGps`) 
VALUES
    (1, 1498806550534, 1, '1111', null),
    (2, 1498806550544, 2, '1111', '7.720517659169257 N 81.4141845703125 E'),
    (3, 1498806550554, 2, '1111', '7.9570 N 80.7601 E'),
    (4, 1498806550564, 2, '1112', '7.9580 N 80.7601 E'),
    (5, 1498806550584, 1, '1111', null),
    (6, 1498806550574, 1, '1111', '7.758619524427473 N 81.3427734375 E')
```

**Sample Polygon Data**

```
{7.89875012596088, 81.27410888671875
7.7695051383446785, 81.56387329101562
7.528595682934752, 81.38946533203125
7.663358425148971, 81.12716674804688}
```

**We need to fetch all events which comes within polygon region for that specific time.**

I have found [this](http://marcgg.com/blog/2017/03/13/mysql-viewport-gis/) link to achieve above but it requires GPS to be in geometry field, whereas we have it in *varchar* format.

Event GPS is located in plateGps and sourceGps columns of event and source table respectively based on source type.

**Note:** We have huge amount of data in event table, so optimized solution will be required.

I could not find any helpful link to work with big data to achieve required functionality.

Comment: Please tell us which version of MySQL is involved here. Why? the **MySQL geospatial extensions** have improved in recent versions.

Comment: Your first problem if you want to optimize this: Quite simply, you *must* get your `source.sourceGps` and `event.plateGps` text columns translated so they are stored in separate `FLOAT` columns for latitude and longitude. You can't put numerically meaningful indexes on your text columns. (West longitude is negative, south latitude is negative.)

Comment: @O.Jones.. We are using MySql 5.7

Comment: @O.Jones.. As we already have millions of data, so at this point changing schema is very difficult. Can you please specify solution with existing schema.

Comment: With respect: Changing your schema may indeed be difficult. But doing your geocoding task with the schema you have is also very difficult, and doing it efficiently is practically impossible. Indexes are the way you get efficient MySQL operations, and indexes on text strings like `'7.720517659169257 N 81.4141845703125 E'` are useless. It will take a day of design and two hours of table-loading to adopt a new schema.

Comment: Bite the bullet.  Converting the current geocoding into `SPATIAL` encoding is a one-time task.  I would use Perl to do it, but other non-SQL languages can also do the task.

Comment: @O.Jones,, I will discuss with my team about it.